# Print iframe with pdf src in mozilla firefox

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, firefox, iframe

JQuery Script

```
function printPdf(url) {
    var iframe = this._printIframe;
    if (!this._printIframe) {
        iframe = this._printIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                iframe.focus();
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
            }, 1);
        };
    }
    iframe.src = url;
}
```

Above script work in chrome but in mozilla that's download pdf not print